# Validate Specific Format

Tags: javascript, regex, sapui5

I'm thinking to validate an input of my program that should have this format: *XXXXXXXX-Y*

- `X` are number
- `Y` can be a number or letter
- `-` writes automatically

So that's the reason why. [Input type](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.InputType) `"Number"` does not work for this case.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rol_%C3%9Anico_Tributario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical use case for [`sap.m.MaskInput`](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/generic-mask-input/)<sup>[[API]](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.MaskInput)</sup>. Using MaskInput eliminates the need to validate (on front-end) as it doesn't allow invalid characters even to be typed which also improves UX.

Of course, you can also keep using `sap.m.Input`. In that case, you can use the type `sap.ui.model.(odata.)type.String` with the constraint `search` which awaits a regex. Wrong inputs won't be passed to the bound model.

Here is a demo showcasing both examples:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Messaging",
], async (XMLView, JSONModel, Messaging) => {
  "use strict";
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      height="100%"
      displayBlock="true"
    >
      <App>
        <Page
          class="sapUiNoContentPadding"
          title="Allowing Specific Format Only"
        >
          <MessageStrip
            class="sapUiTinyMarginTop sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd"
            text="Allowed sequence: &lt;em>XXXXXXXX-Y&lt;/em>"
            showIcon="true"
            enableFormattedText="true"
          />
          <form:SimpleForm
            editable="true"
            layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
            labelSpanM="5"
          >
            <Label text="Restricting inputs via MaskInput" />
            <MaskInput mask="99.999.999-Y">
              <rules>
                <MaskInputRule
                  maskFormatSymbol="Y"
                  regex="[a-zA-Z0-9]"
                />
              </rules>
            </MaskInput>
            <Label text="Validating inputs via binding type" />
            <Input xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
              core:require="{ StringType: 'sap/ui/model/type/String' }"
              value="{
                path: '/value',
                type: 'StringType',
                constraints: {
                  search: '[0-9]{8,}-[a-zA-Z]'
                }
              }"
            />
          </form:SimpleForm>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: new JSONModel({ value: "" }),
  });
  Messaging.registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-onInit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludeJQueryCompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

PS: You might wonder why the `"9"` works in the `mask` definition.  [By default](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/32a2ab9b5b2621f9ef2d330f1e9505ccb377cee0/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/MaskEnabler.js#L513-L524), MaskInput contains the `rule` `/[0-9]/` that has the `maskFormatSymbol` `"9"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Regex to validate

```
var pattern = \[0-9]{8,}-[a-zA-Z]\;
return pattern.test('12345678-A'); //will return true
```

`[0-9]{8,}` - digits for first 8 characters
`-` match -
`[a-zA-Z]` - one character upppercase or lowercase